# WPF : Binding a collection to an itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections

iv'e got a dll consisting of 3 classes which represent a board game :

```
   Board , Pipe , Checker
```

the board is a collection of pipes and the pipes are a collection of checkers

an opponent movement will consist of removing a checker from one pipe and placing it in another .

my board is represented by a grid panel with 23 items-controls ,
i need to bind each item-control to a pipe so as to display the movements on the UI

the player movement would be done by a drop drag between the itemcontrols 
(haven't gotten around to that part yet)

the Checker Class :

```
  public Checker 
  {
      public bool IsMine{get; set;} 
  }
```

the IsMine property needs to be used to determine the Checkers Color .

the Pipe Class : holds an ObservableCollection of checkers

```
  public class Pipe : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public Pipe()
    {
        checkers = new ObservableCollection<Checker>();
    }

    private  ObservableCollection<Checker> checkers {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Checker> Checkers
    {
        get { return checkers; }
        set
        {                               
            checkers = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Checkers"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;            
 }
```

what i need to do is create a 2-way binding between each itemscontrol and it's corresponding Pipe item the add and remove items when the collection changes

i also need a custom converter that will check the IsMine Property and set the objects 
color accordingly (the itemsControl DataItemTemplate is consist of an Ellipse which would 
represent each checker).

till now iv'e just populates the collections and set them as the items source for each items control

for example :

```
   Pipe23.ItemsSource = board.Pipes[23].Checkers;
```

i am faced with 2 challenges :
(1) 
ether create a 2-way binding with the OwnerToColor converter in code behind 
    which i couldn't find an example of how this is done .

(2) create this binding in markup but then how could i initialize the starting items 
    in the appropriate pipes

for example :

```
pipe23 starts with 2 checkers 

board.Pipes[23].Checkers.Add(new Checker(true));
board.Pipes[23].Checkers.Add(new Checker(true));
```

any good examples for 2-way binding between collection and itemsControl would be most  appreciated  .

the itemsControl :

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="Pipe23"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"/>
```

the DataTemplate :

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="PipeDataItem" >
          <Ellipse Width="45" Height="45" Fill="{Binding IsMine,Converter={StaticResource MyOwnerToColorConverter}}"></Ellipse> 
     </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i'm starting to think maybe it isn't possible to make a tow way bind
between the itemscontrol and the collection 
i tried adding an ellipse to the item control , which threw an exception stating that no items could be added while the itemscontrol is in use .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the ItemsSource directly, you should create a binding.

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = board.Pipes[23];
b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Checkers");
Pipe23.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work from source to control ,
how would you test it from control to source .
look at the datatemplate in my question above .
if i where to add an ellipse should it update the source collection 
or is there some more consistent way of adding an object of the desired template ?

Comment: i don't see how this is different from 
Pipe23.ItemsSource = board.Pipe[23] 
it updates them as well . 
the only reason i wanted to specify binding as you described is to make it tow-way , so when adding a new Ellipse to a Pipe23(ItemsControl) a Checker 
object would be added to the Pipe (Checker Collection).
but how would it know to make it to a Checker at the source ?
can this be done ?

Comment: You should be modifying your model, and the UI will automatically update. So you would handle the event when a user drags a marker from pipeA to pipeB. In this you would remove the checker from boards.Pipes[A] and add it to boards.Pipes[B]. Since you've bound the collections, you won't need to manually update the UI.

Comment: exactly it's one way source -> target control